# document.getElementById like function for a particular div

Tags: javascript, jquery

document.getElementById will search th whole document and return the result but here i want the same function for a particular div as i want to search the specific div for an id and based on that i want to execute

here is my code

```
if(document.getElementById('myId') ) // but it return the result from whole div 
{
  // Do something
}
else {
  // do something else
}
```

i want something like

```
if(document.getElementById('myId') in specific div) \\ how to do this
```

Comment: `id` attributes should be unique, so searching by `id` within another div should be irrelevant.

Comment: Are you looking for a child div of 'myId' with a given id?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - it's not entirely irrelevant.  There should be no id dups, but sometimes you only want to return the elem with the id if it's in a specific container so a "#parent #child" selector can sometimes be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to search for a specific `id` for all `div`

I assume that you know the `id` you want to search

You can itenerate the `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` like this

```
var myID = 4;

for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('div').length; i++){
    var res = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i+1].id;
    if(res == myID){
        document.body.innerHTML = res;
        break;
    }
}
```

And this would be your **HTML** look like:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
<div id="5"></div>
<div id="6"></div>
```

See [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/a8XHn/)

**Or** I further assume that yor **HTML** code is look something like this:

```
<div id="myId">
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
    <div id="3"></div>
    <div id="4"></div>
    <div id="5"></div>
    <div id="6"></div>
</div>
```

Then you can itenerate the `document.getElementById('myId').getElementsByTagName('div')` like this:

```
var myID = 3;

for (var i = 0; i < document.getElementById('myId').getElementsByTagName('div').length; i++){
    var res = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[i+1].id;
    if(res == myID){
        document.body.innerHTML = res;
        break;
    }
}
```

And See [Another Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/a8XHn/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Let say, you are looking for an element(div) with id "childId" within parent div with id "parentId". The Jquery code would be:

```
$("#parentId").find("#childId")
```

As a shortform, you can even do

```
$("#parentId #childId")
```

Since the above statement will find children in any depth, if you would want a direct child search, (first level child)

```
$("#parentId > #childId")
```

Generally ids are unique within the page (or atleast are recommended to be :) ). In such a case, you can directly do

```
$("#childId")
```

and still get the child element.

Whichever applies.

Answer (score 0):

id attributes should be unique, so searching an element with an id within another element it's the same as search for that id directly in the whole DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You can return an element **only** if it is a child of a particular element by using a querySelector:

```
document.getElementById('evalBar').querySelector('#button_2');
```

/*  returned value: (html BUTTON)
[object HTMLButtonElement]
*/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the querySelector function. IMPORTANT: check browser compatibility!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector

Example:

```
        <div id="foo">
            <div id="bar">
                this is foo-bar
            </div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var bar = document.querySelector("#foo #bar")

            alert(bar.innerHTML); // result: alert message "this is foo-bar"
        </script>
```